# Post-upgrade problems: Image URL in DB, but not showing

Tags: images

Hey I'm a WP noob but I was given the task of upgrading WP from 3.2.x to 3.5.x. Now some images aren't showing.

Here's the chunk of code responsible for it:

```
$query = "select w1.guid,w2.post_title, w1.ID from wp_posts w1,wp_posts w2 where w2.id=w1.post_parent and w1.post_type='attachment' and w1.post_parent in (".$post_a.") and w2.post_status='publish' ORDER BY w2.post_date DESC ".$lim_." ";

$terms = $wpdb->get_results($query);
print_r($terms); // for debugging
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($terms); $i++) {
    $gallery_image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($terms[$i]->ID, 'thumbnail');

    if ($size != "") {
        $result_[$i] = '<img src="'.$gallery_image_thumb[0].'" alt="'.$terms[$i]->post_title.'" border="3"> ';
    } else {
        $result_[$i] = '<img src="'.$gallery_image_thumb[0].'" alt="'.$terms[$i]->post_title.'" border="0">';
    }
```

So for one section it shows images properly, but for another it generates images with empty `src`s.

So I printed out the `$terms` search results array and this is what comes up for the section that works:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [guid] => http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/jmc-body.jpg [post_title] => jmc-body [ID] => 28358 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [guid] => http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/jmc-80.jpg [post_title] => jmc-80 [ID] => 28356 )`

while this is the `$terms` array for the section that doesn't work:

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [guid] => http://www.mysite.com/images/mysite/gallery_latest_images/ckc721.jpg [post_title] => CKC_704 [ID] => 25367 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [guid] => http://www.mysite.com/images/mysite/gallery_latest_images/jmc1294toy.jpg [post_title] => JMC_1294 [ID] => 25366 )`

So I'm guessing that I need to add an if/else condition on this line: $gallery_image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($terms[$i]->ID, 'thumbnail'); ? I assume `wp_get_attachment_image_src` looks only in uploads? Does anyone know a clean way of fixing this? I'm not sure what kind of if/else statement I could do... unless it were a regex for matching the guid?

Comment: What should be the correct URL(s) for the broken images?

Comment: The guids listed above all have the right URLs, but `wp_get_attachment_image_src($terms[$i]->ID, 'thumbnail');` doesn't seem to work on the second array for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to produce working code for this. I will edit the answer if I get the chance.

In the meantime, [you probably want a filter on `upload_dir`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L1587) to alter that path.

Your code would look something like this then:

```
function alter_upload_wpse_107016($upload) {
  remove_filter('upload_dir','alter_upload_wpse_107016');
  // alter $upload array
  return $upload;
}
if (1 === preg_match('|regex-to-check-guid|',$terms[$i]->guid) {
  add_filter('upload_dir','alter_upload_wpse_107016');
}
$gallery_image_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($terms[$i]->ID, 'thumbnail');
```

That is completely untested and written entirely from memory. No promises but maybe it will get you started.

By the way, the `guid` [***is not*** an URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note), however much it may look like one, and should not be used as such (even though it *was* used as such by WordPress prior to something like 2.7).

Comment: what does $upload stand for/

Comment: That is the information passed into the filter by WordPress. `var_dump` it or look at the source I linked to-- second parameter of `apply_filters`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to `alter $upload array` as you wrote above. What would I do there? I copied and pasted your code and it didn't change

Comment: using $terms[$i]->guid like this: `'<img src="'.$terms[$i]->guid.'" alt="'.$terms[$i]->post_title.'" border="3"> '` worked... but you said it's bad to do right?

Comment: It is not a good long-term solution. You really need to get the images migrated or get filters in place to load from that directory correctly.

Comment: How would I migrate the images properly? I feel like things were lost in the WP upgrade process. wp_get_attachment_image_src($terms[0]->ID, 'thumbnail'); don't seem to work on the images in `/images/mysite/...`

Comment: That is a big question. Why were images ever uploaded to that location anyway? Had the Core code of the previous site been altered?